# Set session variable with select box via Ajax with Coldfusion

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I'm trying to set a coldfusion session variable when the value of a select box changes. However I get an error on an alert box saying "Object HTMLSelectElement" and doesnt change the session variable. Any help would be great.

Code:

Form.cfm

```
<cfset session.item1 = 0>
<cfselect name="item1" class="form-control" id="item1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
</cfselect>
```

Script

```
$('#item1').change( function() {
          var item1Selected = $('#item1').val(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '\components.cfc?method=getItem1', // You repeated "url:" in your url
            data: {item1: item1Selected}, // added missing final comma
            success: function(item1Selected) { alert(item1); }
          });
        });
```

Components.cfc

```
<cffunction name="getItem1" access="remote" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="item1" type="any" required="yes">
        <cfset session.item1 = #argument.item1#>

        <cfreturn />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I am not sure that passing     item1 as data in the ajax call will come over to CF as an argument.  I would append     '&item1=' + item1Selected to the end of the url and remove the data element.  Otherwise, you would have to use a getHTTPRequestData in your function and deserialize the data.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<cfset session.item1 = #argument.item1#>
```

to this:

```
<cfset session.item1 = arguments.item1>
```

The correct scope is arguments, the plural of argument.  Plus, you don't need the pound signs.

Not related to your question, but if you get your CF code to work using CF only, this sort of troubleshooting becomes a lot easier.

Comment: *using CF only* Along those lines, you can test "remote" functions in a browser: `http://yourserver/yourcomponent.cfc?method=yourMethod&param1=blahblah`. If it throws an error, you know it won't work from jQuery either.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for comments)

In addition to [Dan's comments about the error in the CFFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42631351/104223), two other issues that may prevent the code from behaving as you expect:

1. Your `success()` function defines the response variable as `item1Selected`. By using alert(`item1`) you are actually displaying the `<select>` element, not the response from the ajax call.
2. The `cffunction` does not actually return anything, ie `<cfreturn />` So even if you fix the variable name, the response will be undefined or blank. Returning a response is not required. However, if you did want to return some sort of data to `success()` you need to modify the function to return something (JSON, etcetera).